# term for a "squared simplex"

Tags: geometry, terminology

The set of points 
$$\{(x_0,...,x_n)|\forall{i}: x_i \in [0,1], \ and \ x_0+..+x_n=1\}$$
is an *n-simplex*.

What can I call a set of points:

$$\{(x_0,...,x_n,y_0,...,y_n)|\forall{i}: x_i,y_i \in [0,1], \ and \ x_0+...+x_n = 1 \ and \ y_0+...+y_n=1\}$$ ?

for $n=1$, a 1-simplex is a line segment, and my shape is a square. This shape is like a "square simplex" - it is a simplex in $n$ dimensions, and a simplex in the other $n$ dimensions, but not in $2n$ dimensions.

Does this shape has a standard name? If not, what could be a good name for it?

Comment: It looks like your set is an intersection of two faces of a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$.

Comment: A product of simplices?

Comment: @AdamSaltz Is this a cartesian product of simplices?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a standard name for the construction.  Using your definition (simplices are $n$-tuples satisfying some relation) then yes, this is the cartesian product of two simplices.

Comment: @AdamSaltz thanks, "cartesian product of simplices" seems like a good term.

Comment: Interestingly, as @Sigur said, this cartesian product of simplices in $R^{n+1}$ is also contained in a simplex in $R^{2n+2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call an"$n$-simplex" is in fact an $n$-dimensional hyperplane in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. The second expression defines a $2n$-dimensional hyperplane in $\Bbb R^{2n+2}$.

**Edit:** Regarding your revised question: what you have isn't a type of simplex but a type of square (i.e. a square of a simplex). The term "simplex square" seems not to be laden with other mathematical meanings; so it would be one to consider.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in the definition of simplex. I corrected the question. I hope it is OK now.